# How to get a JTextField event that started a pop up menu in Java?

Tags: java, events, swing, popup, jtextfield

I have a JTextField that represents a day, such as "Sunday", when I left mouse click on it, it changes background color, when I right mouse click on it, a pop up menu comes up, after I click on a menu item, such as "1st of month", it gets the value, closes the menu and then change the bgcolor, my code looks like this :

```
    JTextField dayHeading=new JTextField("Su");
......
    final JPopupMenu Pmenu;
    JMenuItem menuItem;
    Pmenu=new JPopupMenu();
    menuItem=new JMenuItem("1st of month");
    Pmenu.add(menuItem);
    menuItem=new JMenuItem("2nd of month");
    Pmenu.add(menuItem);
......
    menuItem.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
      public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e)
      {
        System.out.println(((JMenuItem)e.getComponent()).getText());
        onHeadingClicked(e);  // Error : java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JMenuItem cannot be cast to javax.swing.JTextField
                              // How to get the orininal JTextField event that started this pop up menu, so I can pass it onto  onHeadingClicked() ?
      }
    });
......
    dayHeading.setEditable(false);
    dayHeading.setFocusable(false);
    dayHeading.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent evt)
        {
          if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) onHeadingClicked(evt);
          else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt)) Pmenu.show(evt.getComponent(),evt.getX(),evt.getY());
        }
    });

......
    void onHeadingClicked(final java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
    {
      final javax.swing.JTextField fld=(javax.swing.JTextField) evt.getSource();
...
    }
```

My question is : in the menuItem.addMouseListener section, how to get the orininal JTextField event that started this pop up menu, so I can pass it onto onHeadingClicked() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for working examples. The MouseListener is only used to display the popup, not handle the selection of the menu item. You need to add an ActionListener to each menu item to handle the selection.

In this case the ActionEvent will be the menu item. Therefore you should be able to use the getSource() method of the ActionEvent to get the menu item. Then you can use the getParent() method to get the popup menu. Finally you can use the getInvoker() method to get the text field. Something like:

```
JMenuItem mi = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu)mi.getParent();
JTextField tf = (JTextField)popup.getInvoker();
```

However, a better approach is to create your menu item using an Action. The tutorial also has a section on "How to Use Actions", which contains an explanation and example. In this case you would extend TextAction. Now when the Action is invoked you can simply use the getFocusedComponent() method of the Action to get the text field. Something like:

```
class SelectAll extends TextAction
{
    public SelectAll()
    {
        super("Select All");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
        component.selectAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the ClassCastException because the mouselistener is not on the JTextField but on the JMenuItem. They're 2 distinct components not related to each other so the JMenuItem doesn't know that the JTextField 'started it', so unless you do the association yourself you can't really achieve this directly.

Why dont you change your class a little bit, instead of using anonymous adapters:

Make your class implement MouseListener directly.

Implement the methods of the MouseListener interface (mainly mouseReleased(), mousePressed() etc.) Those that you're not interested in just leave them empty (you still need to have them declared).

Then change this:

```
menuItem.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
      public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e)
      {
        System.out.println(((JMenuItem)e.getComponent()).getText());
        onHeadingClicked(e);  // Error : java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JMenuItem cannot be cast to javax.swing.JTextField
                              // How to get the orininal JTextField event that started this pop up menu, so I can pass it onto  onHeadingClicked() ?
      }
    });
```

to this:

```
menuItem.addMouseListener(this);
```

This way you have access to all the components in your class, and you can access your JTextField object.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a quick fix :

```
  MouseEvent Right_Click_Mouse_Event;

...
    menuItem.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
      public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e)
      {
        Out(((JMenuItem)e.getComponent()).getText());
        onHeadingClicked(Right_Click_Mouse_Event,((JMenuItem)e.getComponent()).getText());
      }
    });
...
      dayHeading.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
      {
        public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent evt)
        {
          if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) onHeadingClicked(evt,"");
          else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt))
          {
            Pmenu.show(evt.getComponent(),evt.getX(),evt.getY());
            Right_Click_Mouse_Event=evt;
          }
        }
      });
...
  void onHeadingClicked(final java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt,String Order_In_Month)
  {
    final javax.swing.JTextField fld=(javax.swing.JTextField) evt.getSource();
...
  }
```

Works Ok.

Comment: this is not the proper solution.

Comment: I agree, but when might this cause a problem ?

Comment: I didn't look at your code too closely, so I don't know what you have changed. The main problem is nobody will ever understand the code because there are standard ways to solve this problem as is demonstrated in the tutorials. But I guess one big problem is that users will not be able to use the keyboard to select a menu item. You can never assume people will only use a mouse. In fact advanced users always prefer to use the keyboard.

Comment: Irrespective of whether this works or not, its quite a messy hack imho. Passing a previous mouse click event (when the menu was shown) to a future event (when the menu item was chosen) is just an invitation for errors and confusion. Instead of an anonymous adapter just implement the MouseListener yourself and you'll have access to all your classes in a simple Object Oriented clean way! Anonymous adapters are just there to use in simple straightforward situations, scenarios like this start pointing towards having a proper class implementing the interface properly.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this::

```
private void CommonMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem)evt.getSource();         // source is clicked JMenuItem
    JPopupMenu popupMenu = (JPopupMenu)menuItem.getParent(); // get parent JPopupMenu
    Component component = popupMenu.getInvoker();            // who called JPopupMenu?
    System.out.println(component.getName());                 // get component name
}
```

For this to work you will need to name your components that have JPopupMenus